# place a div at the bottom in a Pintetest-like layout

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to use a pinterest-like layout in my page. Each posts by user in placed in a div. In a simplified form, the layout looks like this

```
Post with 11 likes    Post with 4 likes      Post with 1 likes
Post with 9 likes     Post with 2 likes
```

This is the CSS that I used for the pinterest payout, for HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="post">Post1</div>
<div class="post">Post2</div>
<div class="post">post3</div>
</div>
```

and for CSS;

```
.container{
column-count: 4;
    column-gap: 10px;
    margin:0 auto;   
    padding:10px;
}

.post { 
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 0 1em;
    width: 220px;

}
```

Because I have multiple pages, I want to place page numbers(which are links to other pages)at the bottom of the page. In other words I want the layout looks like this:

```
Post with 11 likes    Post with 4 likes      Post with 1 likes
Post with 9 likes     Post with 2 likes

                     page:1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

I use the following CSS:

```
#bottom{
 position:fixed
 bottom: 0;
 display:inline-block;
}
```

The problem is that the actual result looks like this:

```
Post with 11 likes    Post with 4 likes      Post with 1 likes
Post with 9 likes     Post with 2 likes      Page:1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

After I add more posts, it becomes this:

```
Post with 20 likes    Post with 7 likes      Post with 1 like
Post with 11 likes    Post with 4 likes      Page:1 2 3 4 5 6 7
Post with 9 likes     Post with 3 likes      
Post with 8 likes     Post with 2 likes
```

This is because the page thinks right below the "post with 1 like" is the bottom of the page. How can I place my page number at the bottom of the page instead of right below the specific post?

Thank you guys I fixed my problem! I applied position:fixed to place all the page numbers at the bottom, but all the numbers were squeezed together because I display the numbers in a php for loop. Now I place the bottom element outside of the for loop and solved the problem.

Comment: where is your `#bottom` element? Give us a working demo of what you have please so we can see the current problem.

Comment: oh it could be because you're missing a semicolon after `position: fixed`

Comment: the bottom element is after the <div id=container></div>

Comment: Thanks! Adding position:fixed place it a the bottom, now the problem is all the numbers are squeezed together in a nasty dot. (even though I'm using display:inline-block), how can I fix this?

Comment: Set a width to the element.

Comment: @gravition by trying first, then asking a new, proper question with complete code of the problem if you can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [manual](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/) on sticky footers.

Your code should also work, but it doesn't sound like `position: fixed` is what you're aiming for... It will just fixate the div on the bottom of the screen regardless of the scroll.

also, `display: inline-block` and `position: fixed` don't make sense together. lose the former.

If you just want the div to be under all the rest and not necessarily at the bottom of the page, just take it out of the div that wraps the posts and give is a `display: block`